# How to check if query parameter is empty?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

The idea is to generate a list of board games based on parameters like player count, time and/or difficulty level. I am using the **QUERY** function in **Google Sheets**.

I have a sheet that has a list of board games. They have separate columns for Title, the minimum number of players, the maximum number of players, difficulty, playtime.

In a second sheet, I have 3 cells which a user can use to write player count (B1), Difficulty (B2) and/or Playtime (B3).

The idea is that with all 3 cells empty, it doesn't show anything, but then you can fill out any or even all of the three cells to filter the complete list of games.

However, if I use one query with all three parameters, if any are empty I get an error.

I've worked around the problem by having multiple nested IFs which check if any of the cells are empty. Based on this, it runs a slightly different QUERY function (i.e., excluding the empty cell). However, this is difficult to troubleshoot and will be a pain to modify if I want to add any additional parameters.

This is the full query:

```
=QUERY('Lista gier'!A1:H424;"select A,C,D,E,F where C<="&B1&" AND D>="&B1&" AND E='"&B2&"' AND F<="&B12&" AND F>=(0.5*"&B12&") AND B='Gra'");
```

Expected results are the proper list of games, but I always receive an error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "C "" at line 1, column 24. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax would be:

```
=QUERY('Lista gier'!A1:H424; 
 "select A,C,D,E,F 
  where C <= "&B1&" 
    and D >= "&B1&" 
    and E  = '"&B2&"' 
    and F <= "&B12&" 
    and F >= "&0,5*B12&" 
    and B  = 'Gra'"; 0)
```

assuming that **B1** and **B12** are numeric and **B2** is a text string

Comment: I get a formula parse error when I use your formula. Anyway, how is that different besides the fact that it skips the headers?

Comment: @Exon9 fixed, try now